# Firebase dual app deployment sharing one database, storage and Auth

Tags: web-applications, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-hosting

Currently using firebase CLI I first deploy hosting to a staging app before I deploy to the default project production app hosting.  The staging app is linked fully with the production apps creationals and database. Using this technique I am wondering if it is possible to develop two separate apps that share the same firebase database, hosting, & auth. Use case: Uber drivers see a different app , uber riders see a different app.  Additionally, serve the main user app from www.example.com and serve the secondary app via driver.example.com

Comment: It's possible, sort of. You could just deploy Firebase Hosting to two different projects while using `firebase.initializeApp()` for the same project in each app's JS. However, Firebase Hosting presently does not support multiple subdomains on the same apex domain so you'd have to do e.g. `www.example.com` and `www.example-driver.com` (this is something we're working on improving).